# TypeError: Cannot read property 'uid' of null

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am trying to log in with a phone number in my app with firebase but I am facing issue with the login process. I'm not able to login with a phone number in firebase but if I register with a phone number and redirect to the homepage it's working properly. I am using the same method to login, but I got the issue like `TypeError: Cannot read property 'uid' of null` but I an successfully getting all the console values. I don't know what is being the issue here. But that error is displaying in 3 times repeatedly,

Here is my code:

```
    renderLoginButton() {
        if (this.props.loading) {
          return (
            <Spinner size="large" />
          );
        }

        return (
          <Button
          style={{ alignSelf: 'flex-start' }}
            onPress={this.onLoginBtnClicked.bind(this)}
          >
            Login
          </Button>
        );
      }
```

onLoginBtnClicked() {

```
    const { contact, password } = this.props;
    const error =  Validator('password', password) ||  Validator('contact', contact);

    if (error !== null) {
      Alert.alert(error);
    } else {
          console.log('else');
        // this.props.loginUser({ contact, password});

        const mobileNo = '+91'+contact;
        firebase.auth().signInWithPhoneNumber(mobileNo)
        .then(confirmResult =>
            console.log(confirmResult),
            curr = firebase.auth(),
            console.log("curr"+JSON.stringify(curr)),
            this.setState({ data: curr}),
            NavigationService.navigate('Home')
        )
        .catch(error => console(error.message) );
    }

}
```

CustomDrawerComponent.js

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Image, Text } from 'react-native';
import { DrawerItems } from 'react-navigation';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import { fetchUserDetails } from '../actions';

class CustomDrawerContentComponent extends Component {

  state = {
    uri: '',
    isfailed: ''
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.fetchUserDetails();
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    let uri = '';
    if (nextProps.ProfilePic !== '') {
      uri = nextProps.ProfilePic;
      this.setState({ uri, isfailed: false });
    } else {
      uri = '../images/ic_person_24px.png';
      this.setState({ uri, isfailed: true });
    }

    this.setState({ uri });
  }

  renderProfileImage() {
    if (!this.state.isfailed) {
      return (
        <Image
          style={styles.profileImageStyle}
          source={{ uri: (this.state.uri) }}
        />
      );
    }
    return (
      <Image
        style={styles.profileImageStyle}
        source={require('../images/ic_person_24px.png')}
      />
    );
  }

  render() {
    console.log('Profile Pic :: ', this.props.ProfilePic);
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {this.renderProfileImage()}
        <Text style={styles.textStyle}>
          {this.props.name} - {this.props.category}
        </Text>
        <DrawerItems {...this.props} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = {
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    paddingLeft: 10
  },
  textStyle: {
    fontSize: 14,
    textAlign: 'left',
    color: '#000000'
  },
  profileImageStyle: {
    alignSelf: 'flex-start',
    marginTop: 16,
    padding: 10,
    width: 40,
    height: 40,
    borderRadius: 75
  }
};

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  const { userprofile } = state;
  return userprofile;
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchUserDetails })(CustomDrawerContentComponent);
```

callStack:

[image][image]

Comment: You need to post the code for `CustomDrawerComponent`, where you're using the `uid` or a sample codebase to reproduce the problem.

Comment: code is update please check and draw me to the issuse

Comment: The `uid` doesn't seem to be present here, can you share a sample codebase to repro the problem for thorough checking if that is possible?

Comment: yes exaclty that;s why i wonder why this error is generated

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Why does the `user` return as `undefined` (or even `null`)?

You know there’s a *logged in user*, you just logged in, heck, you can even see the user object in chrome dev tools.

Then why is it still returning undefined? There’s a straight answer to it.

You’re fetching the user object **BEFORE** that object is ready to be used.

Now, this can happen because of several different reasons, but if you follow this 2 "rules" you won’t see that error again.

**Rule #1: Move it out of the `constructor()`**

When you have something like:

```
constructor(){
  this.userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid
}
```

Over half of the time that page loads, the constructor is going to try to get the user before the user is ready, the app is blocking it because the page isn’t fully loaded, so you’re going to be trying to access uid of a property that just isn’t there yet.

When you get your page fully loaded, you can now call to get the `currentUser.uid`

**Rule #2: Make it an Observable**

There’s another approach you can take, that previous Firebase call we just made: firebase.auth().currentUser is synchronous. We can make it asynchronous by subscribing to the auth observable instead.

```
/**
   * When the App component mounts, we listen for any authentication
   * state changes in Firebase.
   * Once subscribed, the 'user' parameter will either be null 
   * (logged out) or an Object (logged in)
   */
  componentDidMount() {
    this.authSubscription = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      this.setState({
        loading: false,
        user,
      });
    });
  }
  /**
   * Don't forget to stop listening for authentication state changes
   * when the component unmounts.
   */
  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.authSubscription();
  }
  render() {
    // The application is initialising
    if (this.state.loading) return null;
    // The user is an Object, so they're logged in
    if (this.state.user) return <LoggedIn />;
    // The user is null, so they're logged out
    return <LoggedOut />;
  }
}
```

Source article: [Why does Firebase return `undefined` when fetching the `uid`?](https://javebratt.com/firebase-user-undefined/)

A good tutorial for React Native will be here: [Getting started with Firebase Authentication on React Native](https://blog.invertase.io/getting-started-with-firebase-authentication-on-react-native-a1ed3d2d6d91)
Since, your code did not show much, I hope you make an update to your question to show more code, so I might be able to look through.

Comment: Thank you so much for replying but i already did tried this solution which is not working for me and as i have limit for code uploading on this community i m not able to show whole code over here

Comment: @MahiParmar or you can find it here https://medium.com/react-native-training/react-native-firebase-authentication-7652e1d2c8a2

Comment: Thanks again for sharing knowledge but my only requirement is to login with phone number only and not email.

Comment: I know, but your main problem is your code is not getting the auth info, which is likely due to your app load to other event before you got the auth.  Therefore, you need to adjust your code style only. :)

Comment: Your scenario now is like you are taking a bus (your app), you paid for the bus ticket at the terminal (signing in) but you forgot to get the ticket from the counter (didn't get the respond from the auth) and get up to the bus straight away (next activity/event that is after login).  After you got up the bus, the bus driver asks for your ticket and you realize you don't have the ticket with you (uid = null).