# How to set a firestore reference async in service depening on getting UID from other service?

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, observable, angular-services

Basically I want to do this.

**ProjectService:**

```
  privateFolderRef = this.db.collection('users').doc('private').collection(this.userService.uniqueId);
  publicFolderRef = this.db.collection('users').doc('public').collection(this.userService.uniqueId;
//later in service
this.getProjects() { this.privateFolderRef.doc('name')};//not async
```

**UserService:**

```
  get uniqueId() {
    return this.afAuth.auth.currentUser.uid;
  }
```

Problem is currentUser is async an not always ready. So basically how would I assure that my getter function always returns a uid and what can I do to assure a method that uses that ref waits for the refs to be set in a clean way?

I know about this: [TypeError: Cannot read property 'uid' of null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52254513/typeerror-cannot-read-property-uid-of-null)

Waiting in the component would leave me with a lot of duplication. Don't really want to do it that way. Has someone found a solution to do it cleaner in a service?

**Solved** 
There is no way to retrieve a consistent UID from another service, so I solved it this way. Doing it in the service itself.

```
  privateFolderRef;
  publicFolderRef

  constructor(
    private db: AngularFirestore,
    public afAuth: AngularFireAuth
  ) {
    this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(user => {
      this.privateFolderRef = this.db.collection('users').doc('private').collection(user.uid);
      this.publicFolderRef = this.db.collection('users').doc('public').collection(user.uid);
    })
  }
```

**Update**
Does not work in all cases, on reload the constructor function is executed after a normal method call in the class. Returns undefined crashes the app.

**Update 2**
The only way in which I was sure auth was not null at a certain point was to wait in the component itself. That gave me the most control over when a user was really returned. What I really wanted is a central point where I wait for the user (a service) and if that is ready then load a component. The way it is done now will cause a lot of duplication since components work independently from each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should wait for `afAuth` to initiazlize where you need `uniqueID`.
e.g. in ProjectService you get:

```
// wait here for afAuth to be ready, you have to inject it.
privateFolderRef = this.db.collection('users').doc('private').collection(this.userService.uniqueId);
publicFolderRef = this.db.collection('users').doc('public').collection(this.userService.uniqueId);
```

Depending on `afAuth` realization you might `subscribe` to it if possible, there could be an option.

**EDIT:**

If you have an access to `afAuth` service and you there's no possibility to detect when its initialized, you can create an Observable of data received.
Check https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/subject

Comment: Not really an option. Observable only emits a data stream. Yes I can set the references to it  when a user is returned, but the rest of the service will already be loaded and some methods will already be called, still crashing the app.

Comment: Ok, maybe you nudged me to the answer. I wait for it in the constructor of my projectsService and set the references, this seems to work! But really, I hold my breath...Will keep on reloading for a while and see if that keeps on working.

Comment: Great, seems to work nicely. Will post the solution. So there seems to be no way from another service. Or maybe there is, but that would complicate it way to much.

Comment: Glad that it worked for you :) The idea is that one service is dependent on another in async way, so you have to wait for it somewhere. You can decide WHERE.

Comment: The problem for me was that a component was also dependent from a service and that service from another service. In the end I just had to wait in the component. I just don't like the approach to wait in the component. I think a component should be as dumb as possible. However thnx anyway.